# Sudden Rerouting of laravel website

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a Laravel Web site which was working fine but for the last two days it is re routing everything to public_html but the link shown in the url bar is the same as what i want .[image]

I cannot seem to understand what the problem is because the routes are ok and the contorllers are also in place?

Answer (score 0):

Is some url with https? Pls look to console f12, select network tab and refresh page. If is 404 in css meybe on production unsuccess style compiled.